What is the difference between $[x:y:0]$ and $[0:0:1]?$
What is the difference between $[x:y:0]$ and $[0:0:1]?$
According to my understanding,  points of the form $[x:y:0]$ are the  line  at infinity
What is the meaning of $[0:0:1]?$
Reference: From [Homogeneous coordinates]:(https://robotics.stanford.edu/~birch/projective/node4.html)

All the ideal points lie on a line, called the ideal line, or the line at infinity, which, once again, is treated just the same as any other line. The ideal line is represented as $(0,0,1)$.


Homogeneous coordinates from An Introduction to Projective Geometry (for computer vision) distinguishes between the homogeneous coordinates of a point and those of a line. A line in the projective plane is a set of all projective points $[X : Y: Z] $ satisfying an equation of the form
$$
aX + bY + cZ = 0 
$$
where $(a, b, c) \ne (0, 0, 0)$ are the parameters of that line. Since $(a, b, c)$ and $(\alpha a, \alpha b, \alpha c)$ represent the same line for any nonzero $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, one can associate every line with the point $[a: b: c]$ in the projective plane.
In this sense, all points $[X : Y : 0]$ are “points at infinity” or “ideal points” and they all satisfy the equation
$$
  0 \cdot X + 0 \cdot Y + 1 \cdot Z = 0
$$
which is the line described by the projective coordinates $[0 : 0 : 1]$, the so-called “ideal line.”

It depends on how you define "infinity". I will give two examples.
point at infinity.
For example, if you are observing a curve defined by $y^2 = x^3 + x$ in the affine space $\mathbb{k}^2$. Then you extend your view by putting the curve in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2$, with equation $y^2 z = x^3 + x z^2$. If you restrict to $U_z=\{[x,y,1] \in \mathbb{P}^2 \}$, you will get the curve in the affine space again.
The points $[x:y:0]$ on the curve are obtained by intersecting the hypersurface $H = \{[x:y:0] \in \mathbb{P}^2 \}$. The points $[0:0:1]$ and $[0:1:0]$ are also on the curve. But $[0:0:1]$ is already in $U_z$, while $[0:1:0] \not\in U_z$. So in this case, $[0:1:0]$ is called the "point at infinity" in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.
line at infinity To see $[x:y:0]$ is the line at infinity, think about $\mathbb{k}^2$ embeds into $\mathbb{P}^2$ via $U_z$. Then all points of form $[x:y:0]$ are not in $U_z$, that is, they look like infinity points with respect to the affine space.
